# xCode - Exception reason of crash report from Apples Crash Report Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception, crash-reports

I tried to fix some bugs of my already distributed App, which I noticed through [Apples crash report service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html), using the xCode Organizer (xCode -> Organizer -> Crashes). It's working fine and I'm able to open the crash report in my project, so xCode is showing me every detail of the crash like the line in my code, where the exception occurs, call stack, etc.

My problem is, that I can't find the exception reason like for example:

```
-[__NSArray0 addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa99b801c40
```

which I need, to 100% identify the reason, why my App crashed on some devices at this line. I already studied Apple's article about [Analyzing Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html) but without success.

Does anybody know, where I can see the reason of a crash in a crash report provided by Apple's Crash Report Service?

Comment: Can you post a crash report?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Right click on the crash report entry in Xcode's Organizer window and select "Show in Finder"
2. Right click on the revealed `.xccrashpoint` file in Finder and select "Show Package Contents"
3. Navigate to the `DistributionInfos/all/Logs/<date-and-uuid>.crash` subfolder within the `.xccrashpoint` file
4. Open the `.crash` file in Console.app
5. This will have the exception type and reason printed alongside the symbolicated stack trace

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true anymore :/ no exception message anywhere in my crash report as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 0):

On OSX developers can provide an annotation before an app (possibly) crashes using the global `__crashreporter_info__` declared like this to be accessible.

```
const char *__crashreporter_info__ = NULL;
asm(".desc ___crashreporter_info__, 0x10");
```

Unfortunately this seems not to be supported on iOS.
@bbum: Is there any way on iOS to annotate crash reports?